# Why do chat posts appear twice at times?

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

Sometimes when I type in chat and post, it appears twice! Why does this happen? (Another user told me it is due to my slow internet connection. But can somebody elaborate and confirm it?) Also if the community knows why this happens, why can't you guys just get rid of this issue? It is really irritating at times when a chat post gets posted twice and I have to remove it. At other times I have to tell others in the chat "Sorry for the double post! Slow internet connetion here!"(And it is irritation to the peak if this too get posted twice! Thankfully it hasn't happened for me!). If someone in here can solve this issue, chat room experience will also be awesome!

---

Here is a screen shot:-

[image]

Note that the 'yeah that' appeared twice!

---

PS :- Note that I said 'Sometimes' in my description above. At 'other' times I see my message *trying* to get posted twice! I mean it gets posted once and then it appears the next time and asks me if I want it to post it(gives me a `retry` button) or just leave it(gives me a `cancel` button too) and I have to opt for the latter.

Comment: It is slow internet. I don't know all the gritty details about how chat works, but if it's your internet I doubt there is much SE can do ;) Are you sure the messages are *actually* getting sent twice? Sometimes it just looks like it on your end.

Comment: yeah the messages actually get posted twice.. that was why "Another user told me..." ...